# How do I wait for the next response for `ReplyingKafkaTemplate`?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, messaging, spring-kafka

I have implemented a relatively simple fire-and-forget query system in Spring Kafka https://github.com/trajano/spring-kafka-stream-example

Currently the behaviour is

> I need an answer to this question, whoever can answer first please tell me and I will trust it.

I want to alter the behaviour somewhat to be

> I need an answer to this question, whoever can answer first **AND passes my internal test condition**, please tell me and I will trust it.

However, I can't see anything that I can do in [ReplyingKafkaTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/requestreply/ReplyingKafkaTemplate.html).  From the API docs I think I may have to extend this class to add that logic somehow.

My guess is to override `onMessage()` but it will be a copy of it before the following line

```java
RequestReplyFuture<K, V, R> future = this.futures.remove(correlationId);
```

to add a consumer record check.

Answer (score 4):

`ReplyingKafkaTemplate` is strictly for one reply for each request; additional replies will be discarded.

We added the `AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate` in 2.3 for exactly this type of scenario - wait for multiple replies or a timeout.

Here is a test case...

```
    @KafkaListener(id = "def1", topics = { D_REQUEST, E_REQUEST, F_REQUEST })
    @SendTo  // default REPLY_TOPIC header
    public String dListener1(String in) {
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "def2", topics = { D_REQUEST, E_REQUEST, F_REQUEST })
    @SendTo  // default REPLY_TOPIC header
    public String dListener2(String in) {
        return in.substring(0, 1) + in.substring(1).toUpperCase();
    }
```

and

```
@Test
public void testAggregateNormal() throws Exception {
    AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate<Integer, String, String> template = aggregatingTemplate(
            new TopicPartitionOffset(D_REPLY, 0), 2);
    try {
        template.setDefaultReplyTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        ProducerRecord<Integer, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(D_REQUEST, null, null, null, "foo");
        RequestReplyFuture<Integer, String, Collection<ConsumerRecord<Integer, String>>> future =
                template.sendAndReceive(record);
        future.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // send ok
        ConsumerRecord<Integer, Collection<ConsumerRecord<Integer, String>>> consumerRecord =
                future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertThat(consumerRecord.value().size()).isEqualTo(2);
        Iterator<ConsumerRecord<Integer, String>> iterator = consumerRecord.value().iterator();
        String value1 = iterator.next().value();
        assertThat(value1).isIn("fOO", "FOO");
        String value2 = iterator.next().value();
        assertThat(value2).isIn("fOO", "FOO");
        assertThat(value2).isNotSameAs(value1);
        assertThat(consumerRecord.topic()).isEqualTo(AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate.AGGREGATED_RESULTS_TOPIC);
    }
    finally {
        template.stop();
        template.destroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I am still on Spring Cloud Greenwich.SR3 which does not have Spring Boot 2.2 and in turn Spring Kafka 2.3.  I had made the following as a stop gap

```java
package net.trajano.springkafka.foo;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.GenericMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * This is a {@link ReplyingKafkaTemplate} that adds a simple validation semantic so it can take multiple responses and
 * choose the first one that matches the validation condition.
 * <p>
 * The use case for this would be providing a farm of topic responders which are decoupled from the calling service and
 * the calling service does not know who would respond and when, but knows some property of the response to consider it
 * <em>valid</em>.
 * <p>
 * This can be explained using a dinner party analogy:
 * <ol>
 * <li>0:00 Kid: Does anyone know what the answers are to the square root of 144 and 2+2?
 * <li>0:01 Uncle 1: 13, 5
 * <li>0:02 Uncle 2: 12, 4
 * <li>0:05 Kid: okay I gathered a few answers,
 * <li>0:05 Kid: Filter out who can't answer 2+2
 * <li>0:05 Kid: The proper answer is 12, 4
 * <li>0:06 Uncle 3: 12, 4
 * <li>0:06 Kid: Sorry uncle 3 you're too slow, so I am ignoring you
 * </ul>
 *
 * @param K key
 * @param V request value
 * @param R response value
 */
public class ValidatingReplyingKafkaTemplate<K, V, R> extends ReplyingKafkaTemplate<K, V, R> {

    private final BiPredicate<K, R> validationPredicate;

    public ValidatingReplyingKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<K, V> producerFactory,
                                           GenericMessageListenerContainer<K, R> replyContainer,
                                           BiPredicate<K, R> validationPredicate) {
        super(producerFactory, replyContainer);
        this.validationPredicate = validationPredicate;
    }

    public ValidatingReplyingKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<K, V> producerFactory, GenericMessageListenerContainer<K, R> replyContainer, boolean autoFlush,
                                           BiPredicate<K, R> validationPredicate) {
        super(producerFactory, replyContainer, autoFlush);
        this.validationPredicate = validationPredicate;
    }

    /**
     * Filter out records that do not pass the validation predicate.
     * <p>
     * This does an initial filter to make sure only the ones with a correlation ID defined is processed.  This does
     * <b>not</b> check whether the correlation ID is something that needs to be considered as {@code futures} is not
     * accessible and it is relying on the super class to perform the extra test.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<K, R>> data) {
        super.onMessage(data.stream()
            .filter(record -> record.headers().lastHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) != null)
            .filter(record -> validationPredicate.test(record.key(), record.value()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

}
```

Usage example in https://github.com/trajano/spring-kafka-stream-example